# A build operation failed. Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

I got notification about flutter upgrade and android studio upgrade. I updated both. But when I tried to run my app on device it gives me error on the error log like this.....

> A build operation failed.
> Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'. Could not create
> task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'. this and
> base files have different roots:
> F:\Flutter\news_api\build\path_provider_android and
> C:\Users\vaagm\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider_android-2.2.1\android.

I tried to solve this error by opening the "android" folder seperately in new window of android studio to resync gradle. But it's not working.

Here is the information...

1: Flutter doctor

[image]

2: Flutter version

[image]

Error looks like.....

[image]